# Нагрузка для проверки быстрой зарядки

Tags: usb, железо, электроника

Существуют ли устройства, которые можно использовать в качестве нагрузки для проверки поддержки и качества быстрой зарядки у зарядного устройства? Как их найти?

Насколько я понимаю, устройство на картинке представляет собой просто 2 резистрора и работает для обычных зарядников, но в случае с быстрой зарядкой устройство должно каким-то образом сообщить заряднику, что оно поддерживает быструю зарядку, после чего он увеличит напряжение. Есть что-то подобное?

[image: пример]

Comment: https://aliexpress.ru/wholesale?SearchText=fast+charger+tester первый же девайс https://aliexpress.ru/item/4000533752241.html

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, вроде бы ты дал ссылку на измеритель (к тому же довольно дорогой). А меня именно нагрузка интересует. Измеритель у меня уже есть [вот такой 10 в 1](https://aliexpress.ru/item/32413546549.html) - с быстрой зарядкой работает.

Comment: Тогда вот =) https://www.ebay.com/itm/113724498336
За дешевизной не гонялся, если еще поискать скорее всего найдется дешевле =) если у вас есть измеритель - можете поискать отдельно блок нагрузки например вот https://www.ebay.com/itm/292988704444 
Искать по ключевым QC Load

Comment: Хм.. Стоит раз в 15-30 дороже, чем хотелось бы. Не пойму, зачем на нём usb-порт. Зачем вентилятор в принципе понятно, но есть сомнения в его необходимости.

Comment: Да, запрос `qc load` вроде полезный. Им вентилятор реально нужен?

Comment: 35WT, вентилятор там необходим, дешевле врятли найдете потому что QC и прочие режимы находятся под патентами, и не так много микросхем умеют переключать режимы, можно попробовать собрать самому, если не лень и не нужна поддержка всех типов быстрых зарядок(QC2\QC3\FC\...)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102961/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--).